# Prove $\Phi_{n+1}$ is orthogonal to all p $\in P_n[a,b]$

Tags: numerical-methods, orthogonality, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $\Phi_j(j=0,1,2,...,n+1)$ be a system of orthogonal polynomials on [a,b].

Prove: $\Phi_{n+1}$ is orthogonal to all p $\in P_n[a,b]$

I'm going to solve like following:

I set $p_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\Phi_k$

$$A= <\Phi_{n+1},p_n(x)> = \int_a^b\Phi_{n+1}p_n(x)dx = \int_a^b\Phi_{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\Phi_kdx = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k\int_a^b\Phi_{n+1}\Phi_kdx $$

Since $\Phi_k \neq \Phi_{n+1}$, A = 0

--> QED

Is it true that we need to check whether $<\Phi_{n+1},p_n(x)>$ = 0? And I think the way I set $p_n(x)$ is incorrect.

Could someone help me please? Thank you.

Comment: So I guess $\;\deg\phi_n=n\;$ ...? And you're working in an inned product space with inner product that integral?

Comment: Yes, deg = n, and I think this "Since $Φ_k≠Φ_n+1, A = 0$ " happens only when $p_n$ is the best approximation of f

Comment: What $\;f\;$ are you talking about? The polynomial $\;\Phi_n\;$ is **always** going to be orthogonal with any linear combination of the polynomials  $\;\Phi_k\;,\;\;k<n\;$ , for any $\;n\;$ .

Comment: I mean any function f. This "The polynomial $Φ_n$ is always going to be orthogonal with any linear combination of the polynomials $Φ_k,k<n$, for any n" is the thing I need to prove here. Can I follow the above technique?

Comment: Of course! You've already solved the problem, since $\;\langle\Phi_{n+1},\,\Phi_k\rangle=0\;\forall\,k\le n$

Comment: @Joanpemo: Thank you a lot. I see now